# Trouble installing vowpal wabbit/accessing boost program options

Tags: c++, macos, boost, vowpalwabbit

I'm trying to install vowpal wabbit on a Mac Mini 2012 running Yosemite OSX.

I couldn't workout how to install boost directly from source forge as John Langford suggests at: https://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit/wiki/Tutorial. Instead I went for the following `sudo port install boost`. This seemed to work OK, and I've verified that the file `program_options.hpp` exists in the location `/opt/local/include/boost/program_options.hpp`.

I then cloned  `vowpal_wabbit` into my root directory and attempted to install with `sudo make install`. When I did this, I got the following error in my terminal, saying that `program_options.hpp` couldn't be found:

[image]

Am I installing boost in the wrong place? Are there any steps I missed? Is there any way to tell vowpal wabbit where to look on installation?

Thanks in advance,

Aaron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you to @arielf for providing some really excellent guidance on getting vowpal wabbit up and running. At the end of the day I wasn't able to get Vowpal Wabbit up and running from source, but I did find a way forward using `brew`. Here was my process:

(1) Install brew (if you haven't done that already) from http://brew.sh/ (per the website, just type `ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"`)

(2) Then type `brew install vowpal-wabbit` (see http://brewformulas.org/VowpalWabbit). Note that the dependencies `Automake`, `Libtool`, `Autocon`, and `Boost` are all required for this brew installation. These should install automatically, but keep an eye out for any informative errors that pop up.

(3) I was interested in using Vowpal Wabbit for variable importance testing using the `var-info` wrapper in the `utl` folder of the source directory. After I confirmed that the `vw` command executed as expected from my terminal, I went ahead and installed the source files from John's GitHub using: `git clone git://github.com/JohnLangford/vowpal_wabbit.git.` **Instead of attempting to install**, however, I just use the wrappers in utl to create handy aliases. For example, on my machine I point to `vw-varinfo` using the call `alias varinfo=/Users/aaronpolhamus/vowpal_wabbit/utl/vw-varinfo`. So far this works like a charm.

Let me know if you have any questions about this process.

Answer (score 1):

You're not installing boost in the wrong place. It is just that on OS-X there appears to be no standard place where it gets installed (ports vs brew, etc.)

Currently, `vw` finds the `boost` includes and libraries via the `make` variables: `BOOST_INCLUDE` and `BOOST_LIBRARY`.

Here's the part I don't understand: when I clone a fresh version of vowpal wabbit from git, and look inside the Mac OS-X clause:

> `ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)`

in my top level `Makefile`, I see it already has what seems to be the right settings for your env:

`BOOST_INCLUDE += -I /opt/local/include
 BOOST_LIBRARY += -L /opt/local/lib`

Could it be you've run `autogen.sh` and it overwrote your original `Makefile`?

Are you running `make vw` at the top level (so it can see these definitions)?

Perhaps a `make clean` before everything else is necessary to remove old dependencies?

Hoping one of these hints would lead you to the solution.

Comment: thank you for the pointers. I suspect that the right answer is buried somewhere in here. Unfortunately, I'm a newbie at working with C++ libs and the Unix command line, so I'll need a bit more guidance. Would you mind filling in for me: (1) How to I access my "top level makefile?" (2) What does it mean to run `make vw` at the top level? (3) At what step would I type `make clean`? I've been attempting the install freshly-downloaded versions of vowpal each time.

Comment: OK, doing a bit more digging. `autogen.sh` seems to point to `/opt/local/share` rather than `/opt/local/include`. if `autogen.sh` gets run when i invoke `make` is it possible that it is simply hard coded to select the wrong path? Can I manually recode this to point it at my boos library?

Comment: Aaron: top level makefile is the file called `Makefile` at the top of the tree when you clone from gihub. `make vw` is what you literally type into the shell/command-line. Starting with `make clean` is to make sure I don't have any old files/artifacts before a clean build. Yes editing `/opt/local/share` to be `/opt/local/include` in your case sounds like the right fix. Alternatively don't run `autogen.sh` at all (it overwrites the original `Makefile`) and just use the pristine `Makefile` in the source tree.  After `git clone` just type `make vw` to build the executable `vowpalwabbit/vw`. HTH.

Comment: thank you again for your guidance. I tried the install from source multiple times and just couldn't get the ball rolling. Following tips from http://qugstart.com/blog/machine-learning/how-i-finally-got-vowpal-wabbit-7-0-installed-on-osx-10-6-snow-leopard/ I was able to get beyond my headache above (seems I was missing a libtools dependency), but then I ran into the problem that my mac was compilign C++ libraries using `gcc`, which uses C++ 4.2.1, which apparently doesn't support `tuple` types. In the end, I finally figured out that brew could make all the pain go away.